# How to get the binary base 2 value to separate Index's in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

Here i convert the Integer to binary Base 2 value.
I want to store each binary 0's and 1's separately in array index.
Just need to learn guys.So please help me to learn by answering `enter code here`this question

here is my code:
But I want to store the values in array as[0]=1,[1]=0,[2]=1;

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value = 5;

        string str = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
        //string value 101
        string[] result = new string[] { str };
        //It gives [0]=101
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code..

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    int value = 5;

    string str = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
    //string value 101

    char [] arr=str.ToCharArray (); // converts the string to array of char

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)  // used to print the content of the array
        Console.WriteLine (arr [i]);
}
```

Hope it works for you..